# Databricks Pyspark- Change excel column format from general to number

Tags: python, pyspark, formatting, azure-data-factory, databricks

I am writing a xlsx file using

```
df.write.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel").option("header",True).mode("overwrite").save(outputPath)
```

and using `df.withColumn()` to change the format to `decimal(15,3)`
I am getting the result correct but in excel i can see like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTXOT.png)

I want this in number format and the file is saved at adls location i already tried openpyxl library but it is not working

This should be the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTR0q.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is because of any one of the following reasons.

You may have kept the decimal in you excel **Number** settings as **0**.

[image]

[image]

Make it 3.

Or by mistake you would have given `DecimalType(15, 0)`

[image]

So either in databricks or in excel you're giving
**Decimal places zero**

Comment: Alright but i want to change this format from databricks not from excel settings

Comment: The problem here is not databricks, it is writing to the file correctly. It depends on where you view the data.